# Antd Custom validator and validateFields are not working together as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, antd

I'm working on a form (`Ant Design` `<Form>`) where I want a custom validation of phone number (as it depends on `country` field and has some extra logic), and other fields validated by `antd` built-in features, so when user submits the form I want all fields to be validated with `validateFields()` passed as an array of field names showing validation errors as usual (red message underneath and an error message in console), but all I'm getting is just a warning message in the console.

Here's a minimal reproduction

[image: Edit confident-goodall-4f0bx]

Am I missing something about how `validator` function works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a if else check in your validatePhone function if value is not empty then run your code and if value is empty simply send a callback in else condition. like that

```js
const validatePhone = (rule: any, value: any, callback: any) => {
  if (value) {
    const countryName = form.getFieldValue('country');
    const country = CountryList.getCode(countryName);
    const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumberFromString(value, country as CountryCode);
    console.log(form.getFieldValue('country'));
    if (countryName && phoneNumber && phoneNumber.isValid()) {
      updatePhonePrefix(prefix.concat(phoneNumber.countryCallingCode as string));
      callback();
    } else {
      callback(`Phone number is not valid for ${countryName}`);
    }
  } else {
    callback();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

what the [antd docs](https://3x.ant.design/components/form/#Customize-validator-do-not-working) recommend is to use async or try-catch block

option 1:

```
const validatePhone = async (rule, value) => {
  // check failing condition
  throw new Error('Something wrong!');
}
```

option 2:

```
const validatePhone = (rule, value, callback) => {
  try {
    throw new Error('Something wrong!');
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here how I handled the error in antd form

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';

function MyCustomForm(props: any) {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [validateFieldsName, setValidateFieldsName] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleValidateFieldNames = (name: string) => {
    const isFieldName = validateFieldsName.find(
      (fieldName) => fieldName === name
    );
    if (isFieldName) return 'onChange';
    return 'onBlur';
  };

  return (
    <Form form={form} layout="vertical">
      <Form.Item
        name="contactNumber"
        label="Contact Number"
        validateTrigger={handleValidateFieldNames('contactNumber')}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please enter contact number!',
          },
          {
            validator(_, value) {
              if (!value || value.length === 10) {
                return Promise.resolve();
              }
              return Promise.reject('Please enter 10 digit Number!');
            },
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Contact number"
          onBlur={() =>
            setValidateFieldsName([...validateFieldsName, 'contactNumber'])
          }
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default MyCustomForm;
```

Comment: i have same issue in my project i have one antd select option and in that i want validate tags Ex. tags either email id or plain text. and there any way to find out this tags is email id or plain text.